# Need a driver for HP Deskjet F2480

Tags: printing, hp

This is a all in one printer (printer, scanner). Tried to run hplip-3.19.1.run according to HP, but seems not working. How to troubleshoot?

Comment: In your particular case you need [`hplip` >= 3.9.10 without proprietary plugin](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). Even 14.04 LTS has 3.14. So simple `sudo apt install hplip` would be enough.